# Why do I always lose this file?

Tags: sd-card, htc-hd2

I run a dual-booted HD2 from SDCard/HaRET with MIUI Android & stock WM6.5.

I keep a copy of [this](http://www.radio21.ro/site/Radio21Live.m3u) file in `\Storage Card\My Documents` for listening in CorePlayer and survive possible hard resets.

However, **everytime**, and I really mean **every** time I boot MIUI this file disappears from the SD card. I'm unable to locate it from Android and when I reboot into Windows I see no traces of it.

Why the hell (can I say hell?) does Android delete the file from SD on every single boot? Does it hate M3U files?

Comment: Most important, I never noticed any other file to be missing. I have lots, and I couldn't check one by one. But no other important file disappeared

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android scans your sd card. When it finds an MP3 playlist (m3u file) it looks for media files in the same path, if it does not find any, it deletes the playlist because it thinks it is empty.

To stop this from happening create a file in the folder with the m3u file called `.nomedia`. This will tell the media scanner to ignore the content in the folder.