# Path of music player playlist file?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, music-player, media-player

Can any one explain me where save android's music player playlist files?

actually, I got problem when i format my SD Card after that no playlist in music player.

I am using samsung galaxy 551 with Android 2.2 froyo.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Where (and how) does Android store music playlists?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/where-and-how-does-android-store-music-playlists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place .m3u files anywhere on sdcard which is under reach of media scanner. Playlist will be displayed in music player once media scanner will complete scanning sdcard.

Path of system-created playlists (playlists are common to all music players): `/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external-xxxxxxx.db` where xxxxxxxx are random numbers. Path can be slightly different based on Android versions & devices.

If you want to backup your playlists, i'd recommend you to use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).

Comment: okay but i want playlists file path created using music player

Comment: @AnkurPatel Updated the question..

Comment: I thought media scanner wanted the m3u in the directory as the media. In the past, it would delete an m3u if it was the only thing in the directory as it thought the media for the playlist had been removed.

Comment: @Ryan Location of m3u file was never a matter. If you open the file in text viewer, you can find path of mp3 files in it. Those paths are relative. One can always use `Absolute` path.

Comment: @SachinShekhar maybe it is [only pls files](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19583/disappearing-deleted-pls-files) this happens to then.